# Getting NaN when I am trying to compute the zeros of a quadratic formula

Tags: java

I have two classes, the quadratic class and the runner class. This is the quadratic class.

```
public class Quadratic {
  double a;
  double b;
  double c;
  public double discrim = (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c);

  public boolean hasSolutions() {
    if(discrim >= 0){
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public double getSolution1() {
    double pos = (b*-1 + Math.sqrt(discrim))/(2*a);
    return pos;
  }
  public double getSolution2() {
    double neg = (b*-1 - Math.sqrt(discrim))/(2*a);
    return neg;
  }


  public Quadratic(double a, double b, double c) {}
}
```

And here is the runner class.

```
public class QuadraticRunner
{

  public static void main( String args [])
  {

    Quadratic test1 = new Quadratic (1, 5, 6);
    Quadratic test2 = new Quadratic (1, -4, 4);
    Quadratic test3 = new Quadratic (1, 0, 3);

    String equation1 = test1.toString();
    boolean hasSolution1 = test1.hasSolutions();
    double solution1 = test1.getSolution1();
    double solution1b = test1.getSolution2();
    String equation2 = test2.toString();
    boolean hasSolution2 = test2.hasSolutions();
    double solution2 = test2.getSolution1();
    double solution2b = test2.getSolution2();
    String equation3 = test3.toString();
    boolean hasSolution3 = test3.hasSolutions();
    double solution3 = test3.getSolution1();
    double solution3b = test3.getSolution2();


    System.out.println(equation1);
    System.out.println(hasSolution1);
    System.out.println(solution1);
    System.out.println(solution1b);
    System.out.println("Expected solutions: -2.0, -3.0");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(equation2);
    System.out.println(hasSolution2);
    System.out.println(solution2);
    System.out.println(solution2b);
    System.out.println("Expected solution: 2.0");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(equation3);
    System.out.println(hasSolution3);
    System.out.println(solution3);
    System.out.println(solution3b);
    System.out.println("NaN");
  }
}
```

When I attempt to run this, the hasSolutions() method works fine, but both getSolution1() and getSolution2() come out as NaN. If the discriminant were negative I would understand, but it isn't negative for all the tests, so I am not sure where I went wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calculating the discriminant before any values are assigned to `a`, `b`, or `c`.  Also, you aren't using the constructor values passed in.

```
double a;
double b;
double c;
public double discrim = (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c);

public Quadratic(double a, double b, double c) {}
```

Because of this, you are dividing `0` by `0` in `getSolution1` and `getSolution2`, which in floating-point arithmetic yields a `NaN`.  (In math it's undefined.)

Move that calculation inside the constructor, after you assign values to `a`, `b`, and `c`.

```
public double discrim;

public Quadratic(double a, double b, double c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    discrim = (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor doesn't set the field values, so `a` has a default value of `0` and you divide by zero when you say `/(2 * a)`. Fix your constructor like,

```
public double discrim; // = (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c);
public Quadratic(double a, double b, double c) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c;
  this.discrim = (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c); // <-- also, move the math here.
}
```